# Do you know why you can't find the zeros of an radical expression if it's simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's an example problem. 
[image: Question]

[image: Answer Part 1]

[image: Answer Part 2]

Why must I take my zeros from the expression in red (otherwise known as the unsimplified version) rather than the expression in blue (otherwise known as the simplified version)?

Answer (score 4):

In this case it doesn't matter much since in the first instance you get a double root. So there's only a single value where the fraction is not defined.

Say however you have something like $$\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{(x+3)(x+2)},$$ then you clearly have two different values where the function is undefined. If you remove the common factors first, it is only on the implicit assumption that such factors don't vanish. Thus, the above expression is equal to $$\frac{x-1}{x+3}$$ only provided $x+2\ne 0.$ Thus even in this form we still have two values where the simplified expression is still undefined -- only one of them is implicit.

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking about this too much. Could you show how that would look graphically?

Comment: @Padarscha:  the first has a hole at $x=-2$ where the fraction is undefined.  The second does not.  You might not see that on a graphing calculator.  It is called a removable singularity, because it makes sense to define the first function to be $-3$ at $x=-2$ so it is continuous.  That works for some problems, but not all.